# I not understanding a cancellation step in Spivak proof.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, inequality, absolute-value

There is a question about this exact same proof but the answer is not satisfying me so I'm going to run it again if you don't mind. I will post the original question after mine.
In his chapter on limits, Spivak uses the following lemma:

> $$\left\lvert x - x_0 \right\rvert < \min\left(1, \frac{\epsilon}{2(\lvert y_0 \rvert+1)}\right)$$ and  $$\lvert y - y_0 \rvert \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2(\lvert x_0\rvert + 1) }$$
> then $$\lvert xy - x_0y_0\rvert < \epsilon$$

So here is his proof:

Since we have $\lvert x - x_0 \rvert < 1$ we have
$$\lvert x \rvert - \lvert x_0 \rvert \leq \lvert x - x_0 \rvert \lt 1$$
so that
$$\vert x \vert \lt 1 + \vert x_0 \vert$$
Thus
$$
\begin{aligned}
\vert xy - x_0y_0\vert &= \vert x(y-y_0) + y_0(x - x_0) \vert \\ 
 &\le \vert x \vert \cdot \vert y - y_0 \vert + \vert y_0 \vert \cdot \vert x - x_0 \vert\\ 
 &\lt (1 + \vert  x_0 \vert) \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{2(\vert x_0 \vert + 1)} + \mathbf{ \vert y_0 \vert \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{2(\vert y_0 \vert + 1 )}} \\
&\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \mathbf{\frac{\epsilon}{2}} = \epsilon 
\end{aligned} 
$$

I have bolded the transformation from the second-last line to the last line that I do not understand.

How do we get

$$  \vert y_0 \vert \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{2(\vert y_0 \vert + 1 )} = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

[Not understanding a cancellation step in an inequality proof from Spivak's Calculus.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634070/not-understanding-a-cancellation-step-in-an-inequality-proof-from-spivaks-calcu)

Comment: Note that the content of next line would imply that $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\frac{|y_0|}{|y_0|+1}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. This is true because $|y_0|<|y_0|+1$ and consequently $\frac{|y_0|}{|y_0|+1}<1$.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation @AlannRosas . That was helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do we get
>
> $$  \vert y_0 \vert \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{2(\vert y_0 \vert + 1 )} = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

This isn't what he used there, he used

$$  \vert y_0 \vert \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{2(\vert y_0 \vert + 1 )} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

which follows from $|y_0|<|y_0|+1$.

Answer (score 3):

What's being used is $$
\frac{|y_0|}{|y_0|+1}< 1
$$since multiplying both sides by $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}>0$ gives the last step. The inequality is true since
$$
\frac{|y_0|}{|y_0|+1}< 1 \iff |y_0| < |y_0|+1 \iff 0 < 1
$$
which is true.